# Is there an elegant cross-implementation way to save multiple records short of specialized parsing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am envisioning something like taking a collection of objects and sending the to a stored procedure in such a way that the collection maps to a TABLE parameter or something. Does something like this exist?

Implementation wise we use SQL server 2008, but I would like to stick to generally supported methods [read close to multiple vendor compatible] if possible. I realize I could do some specialized parsing, and pragmatically I also don't really need to optimize this (i.e. I can just save a single record at a time), but I was wondering if there was a general best practice way to save multiple records via stored procedure?

Comment: actually there seem to be [table parameters](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/) in SQL. There's even [ADO.NET support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) for this

Comment: you can serialize them to xml, pass them as a xml parameter and then insert them into a table selecting from the xml.

Comment: Point: "Stored Procedures" are exactly what is *not* multi-vendor compatible in the SQL world.  Sad but true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there're 2 methods I know of and sadly both of it not cross-implementation.

**xml parameter**:

```
create procedure sp_test1
(
    @Data xml
)
as
begin
  select
      D.r.value('@ID', 'nvarchar(128)') as ID,
      D.r.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(128)') as Name
  from @Data.nodes('Data/row') as D(r)
end;

declare @Data xml

select @Data = (select * from test for xml raw('row'), root('Data'))

exec dbo.sp_test1
    @Data = @Data;
```

**table variable**

```
create procedure sp_test2
(
    @tData tbl_test readonly
)
as
begin
  select * 
  from @tData
end

declare @tData tbl_test

insert into @tData
select * from test

exec dbo.sp_test2
    @tData = @tData;
```

see [**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74e4d/2).

If you ask me, I suggest to use xml:

- You can use xml not only for tabular data, but for nested to
- You don't have to define type every type you want to use another schema
- As far as I remember, once you created a type, you cannot change it and you cannot drop i if there'are a objects using it, so it's not very easy to maintain

I also must warn you, that, from my expirience, xml could be not not so fast for large number of records.